# How do I implement multiple *independent* rows of (vuetify) Pseudo Carousels?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, carousel

I am trying to create a bunch of independently controlled carousels while using 'v-for', so that I can easily update them all with json data later. After playing with this for the last two days, I cannot seem to figure out how to make each carousel independently operated while still using 'v-for' to create many of them.

Here is my Code Pen example to see whats going on.

**https://codepen.io/chris4542/pen/LYRdRZp**

And here's the same code as a snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    model: null,
    rows: [
      {title: 'A'},
      {title: 'B'},
      {title: 'C'}
    ]
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-sheet
      v-for="row in rows"
      :key="row.title"
      class="mx-auto"
      elevation="8"
      max-width="800"
    >
      <v-subheader>
        <h2>{{row.title}}</h2>
      </v-subheader>
      <v-slide-group
        v-model="model"
        class="pa-4"
        center-active
        show-arrows
      >
        <v-slide-item
          v-for="n in 15"
          :key="n"
          v-slot="{ active, toggle }"
        >
          <v-card
            :color="active ? 'primary' : 'grey lighten-1'"
            class="ma-4"
            height="200"
            width="100"
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <v-row
              class="fill-height"
              align="center"
              justify="center"
            >
              <v-scale-transition>
                <v-icon
                  v-if="active"
                  color="white"
                  size="48"
                  v-text="'mdi-close-circle-outline'"
                ></v-icon>
              </v-scale-transition>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-slide-item>
      </v-slide-group>
  
      <v-expand-transition>
        <v-sheet
          v-if="model != null"
          height="200"
          tile
        >
          <v-row
            class="fill-height"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <h3 class="title">
              Selected {{ model }}
            </h3>
          </v-row>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-expand-transition>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that every carousel is using the same variable `model`.

You could have an array containing all of the differents carousels values :

`model: [0, 0, 0]`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    model: [0, 0, 0],
    rows: [
      {title: 'A'},
      {title: 'B'},
      {title: 'C'}
    ]
  }),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-sheet
      v-for="(row, idx) in rows"
      :key="row.title"
      class="mx-auto"
      elevation="8"
      max-width="800"
    >
      <v-subheader>
        <h2>{{row.title}}</h2>
      </v-subheader>
      <v-slide-group
        v-model="model[idx]"
        class="pa-4"
        center-active
        show-arrows
      >
        <v-slide-item
          v-for="n in 15"
          :key="n"
          v-slot="{ active, toggle }"
        >
          <v-card
            :color="active ? 'primary' : 'grey lighten-1'"
            class="ma-4"
            height="200"
            width="100"
            @click="toggle"
          >
            <v-row
              class="fill-height"
              align="center"
              justify="center"
            >
              <v-scale-transition>
                <v-icon
                  v-if="active"
                  color="white"
                  size="48"
                  v-text="'mdi-close-circle-outline'"
                ></v-icon>
              </v-scale-transition>
            </v-row>
          </v-card>
        </v-slide-item>
      </v-slide-group>
  
      <v-expand-transition>
        <v-sheet
          v-if="model != null"
          height="200"
          tile
        >
          <v-row
            class="fill-height"
            align="center"
            justify="center"
          >
            <h3 class="title">
              Selected {{ model }}
            </h3>
          </v-row>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-expand-transition>
    </v-sheet>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could do that. That seems to work, and then I can just use the variable as **model[idx]** inside my h3 tag and v-if attribute. I'm going to use this and hopefully its compatible with my needs for filling everything in with regularly updated json files. Also I changed the script to have model=[null,null,null], instead of [0,0,0] because that seems to be a default. Not sure if that makes any difference at all.